# DataGridView does not show updates of the info I have stored in an arraylist

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have the following problem:

When I click the button "end" I show the form "order history". The first time it loads the `DataGridView` it shows all the elements that are stored in the arraylist "bought products"(tabDeProduitsAchete).

However If I go back, and buy another product and succefully add it to the arraylist "bought products"(tabDeProduitsAchete) and I go again to "order history" the `DataGridView` is only displaying the old history it does no refresh or update the new products bought. this is my code. what can I do ? I tried refresh() but it didn't work

```
Private Sub finDeMesAchats_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.DataSource = tabDeProduitsAchete
End Sub


Private Sub butRetour_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butRetour.Click
    Me.Hide()
    formAchatProduit.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: Do the properties in the arraylist implement the inotifypropertychanged interface? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: for binding in a windows form app you should be using a bindinglist instead of an arraylist to hold your data https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Natalia, why don´t you call REBIND in the LOAD event? SOmething like:

```
    DataGridView1.DataSource = tabDeProduitsAchete
    DataGridView1.rebind
```

UPDATE:

You may try also something like this:

```
   Dim source = new BindingSource()
   source.Datasource = TabDeProduitAchete
   DatagridView1.datasource = source
   DatagridView1.rebind   <<< optional
```

Please, try and answer me if it had solved your problem.
Kind regards.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I will try it!